# SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Postgres linked server "cannot get the current row value of column..."

Tags: sql-server-2008, postgresql, linked-server

I have successfully created a linked server between SQL Server 2008 R2 and a Postgres db, and all is working fine, except when I try to run a stored procedure that returns a TEXT column.

The top lines of the stored procedure (function in postgres) that is called are:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_defects()
  RETURNS TABLE(defectid bigint, featurevalues text) AS ...
```

The function obviously executes correctly in postgres, however when I try to execute the function in SQL Server via the linked server:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(POSTGRES, 'SELECT * FROM get_defects()')
```

I get the error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRES" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
>
> Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].featurevalues" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRES".

The problem seems to be when trying to return the TEXT column *featurevalues*, as the following query executes as expected:

```
SELECT defectid
FROM OPENQUERY(POSTGRES, 'SELECT * FROM get_defects()')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: try to use a little bit usual type - for MSSQL varchar(4000) - SELECT defectid bigint, featurevalues::varchar(4000) from get_defects()

Answer (score 0):

I would second Pavel's suggestion for:

```
 SELECT defectid bigint, featurevalues::varchar(4000) from get_defects();
```

I think it deserves some discussion though that SQL is mostly a strictly typed language and so you need to consider that PostgreSQL's handling of such types is not really necessarily what SQL Server may expect.  If SQL Server cannot handle it, you will get errors like this.